# Understanding how strongly typed html helper works

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, razor-2

**Framework:** ASP.NET MVC 3
**Tools:** VS 2012

**Hi guys,**
I'm new to ASP.NET mvc, I have been using strongly typed html helper for some time,I don't understand them completely but know that it can provide type checking and keeps name according to property name,after using it for many times I faced this error constantly and dont seem to have any hint why its occuring tried several google searches but none helped me.

**Error:**
The name 'm' does not exist in the current context
**Code:**
`@Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrginalCont.Title)`

***But this line of code works perfectly fine.***
`@Html.TextBox("origTitle", Model.OrginalCont.Title, new { @readonly = "", @class = "text-rounded", style = "width:425px" })`

Can someone tell me whats going on here.I have used the same `m => m.Name` syntax several times in view but they are all working fine.

**Update:**
Alright I will try to post more code,but as the code may get too long I will try to keep it short and will post code which is related to the problem.

**View**

```
@model TS.MOP.Interface.Models.ProjectTranslationModel
    <div class="form-item">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrginalCont.Title)
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("origTitle", Model.OrginalCont.Title, new { @readonly = "", @class = "text-rounded", style = "width:425px" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
public class ProjectTranslationModel
{
 public int ProjectId { get; set; }
 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Names), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required_ErrorMessage")]
 [DataType(DataType.Text)]
 [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Names), Description = "TranslateLangs_Description", Name = "TranslateLangs_Title")]
 public List<SelectListItem> TranslatableLangSelect { get; set; }
 public TranslatableLanguageEditor TranslatableLangEditor { get; set; }
 public OriginalContent OrginalCont { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult TranslationEdit(int? id)
    {
        if (id.HasValue && User.IsInRole("ContentTranslator"))
        {
            var model = new ProjectTranslationModel();
            model.ProjectId = id.Value;
            var ContentTypeId = 2;//Project Page
            Guid _currentUserId = Guid.Parse(Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString());
            var translatorSettings = db.TranslatorSettings.Where(x => x.UserId == _currentUserId).ToList();
            model.TranslatableLangEditor = new TranslatableLanguageEditor();
            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

            //Original Text
            var originalContent = db.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == id.Value)
                .Select(d => new OriginalContent { Title = d.Title, Content = d.Description, ContentCultureId = d.ProjectType.ContentCultureId }).FirstOrDefault();
            model.OrginalCont = originalContent;

            foreach (var item in translatorSettings)
            {
                //Select List                               
                var li = new SelectListItem();
                if (item.ContentCultureId != originalContent.ContentCultureId)//Dont add the Original Content CultureId to the dropDown
                {
                    li.Value = item.ContentCultureId.ToString();
                    li.Text = item.ContentCulture.Description;
                    list.Add(li);
                }
            }
            model.TranslatableLangSelect = list;
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You say that `m => m.Name` is working fine but `m => m.OrginalCont.Title` isn't. Is `OrginalCont` a public object and is `Title` a public property?

Comment: @RalphJansen yup both `OrginalCont` and `Title` are public property

Comment: Is it just an intellisense error or does your View actually display an error when you try to browse to it?

Comment: @StevenChong Added more code

Comment: Do you really get an error? Because it's true that Visual Studio doesn't show the properties right in the view. Just like @Middas said

Comment: code look fine, maybe add a null check for OrginalCont, since you used .FirstOrDefault()